# Rotation issue imageview

Tags: android, rotation, imageview

Im trying to Rotate my imageview it has a space image I want stars and the main stars rotating. But I cant make it. What kind of scale type I use never worked. Black space still appears. [Sample Image Position](http://mialkan.com/hobi/image.jpg)

Code I used is:

```
        DisplayMetrics metrics ;
    metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int centerX = metrics.widthPixels/2;
    int centerY = metrics.heightPixels/2;
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, centerX, centerY);

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(10000);               // duration in ms
    an.setRepeatCount(-1);                // -1 = infinite repeate
    an.setFillAfter(true);               // keep rotation after animation
    diskView.setAnimation(an);
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: diskView.startAnimation(an);

Comment: pls check the link http://mialkan.com/hobi/image.jpg its rotating but you will see black areas on the corners. Problem is scaling.

Comment: change the image Matrix then, you can get it via getImageMatrix()

Comment: I coulndt do it. I have done this in iOS. Setting the imageview frames out of screen and the scale type it worked. But in android I dont know is there a same way.

Comment: get ghe matrix (getImageMatrix()), change it (preRotate()/postRotate()) and finally set it (setImageMatrix())